# MooTools: Remove CSS class from element

Tags: javascript, css, class, mootools

How do I remove a class from an element? I see in the documentation there's an $().swapClass(), but I don't see a $().removeClass().

Comment: Also, FYI, there is no *swapClass* method in MooTools.

Answer (score 9):

There is indeed a [removeClass()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:removeClass).  Just call it on any element selector:

```
$('element').removeClass(className);
```

Comment: This function has some problems when working with multiple classes - it works correctly only when classes names are passed in the same order as they are in the element.